# Conceptual doubts with quantum-confined lasers

Tags: semiconductor-physics, laser, photon-emission

So, I'm reading about quantum-confined lasers, and I think that I understand the majority of it, but I haven't conceptualized some things that I think are pretty basic. I'll leave this picture here as a reference for what I'm going to ask.

[image: Active region of a multiquantum-dot laser]

-The cladding used here is a semiconductor right?

-When we say that we confine the carriers in the active medium like in the picture, what carriers are we talking about? Electrons? Holes?

-Where are the levels of the laser here? And in what direction is the light emitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The cladding used here is a semiconductor right?

In practice, yes. In principle, though, it could be any material that has the necessary properties. For example, if the laser is optically pumped, you could imagine isolated semiconductor quantum dots on a glass substrate.

I think the diagram is mixing up optical guiding with the gain mechanism. Usually there'd be a separate optical waveguide layer (surrounded by cladding) and the quantum dots would be arranged within that layer. There would also be a current confinement structure to avoid leakage currents around the quantum dots.

> When we say that we confine the carriers in the active medium like in the picture, what carriers are we talking about? Electrons? Holes?

It would be both electrons and holes, but usually we fudge and only do the book-keeping on one of the two carriers (whichever one limits the recombination rate).

> Where are the levels of the laser here?

They're the valence and conduction bands of the semiconductor, as restricted by the quantum dot geometry.

> And in what direction is the light emitted?

That depends on the optical cavity structure built around this gain element. It could be vertical (like in a VCSEL) or lateral (like in an edge-emitting laser diode).